# Manipulate Plot with Controller being difference of two variables

Tags: plotting, manipulate

I'm not sure if this is possible at all or whether manipulate is the best option to plot this, but currently I'm using the following code to plot Function *Func* vs. *t* values for different *x* values.

```
Manipulate[a = -0.5;
b = 0.2;
c = 1;
Func[t_] := a/t^2*(t - x)^2 + b/t*(t - x) + c;
Plot[Func[t], {t, 1, 100}], {x, 1, 100, 1}]
```

What I'm really interested in is to plot *Func* vs. ***t-x*** (**EDIT:** t-x = t minus x being a new variable for plotting purpose only.) and then for different values of *x*. I can't find a way to make this plot. I would appreciate any suggestion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps

```
Manipulate[ParametricPlot[{t-x, a/t^2*(t - x)^2 + b/t*(t - x) + c}, {t, 1, 100},
  AspectRatio -> 1, Frame -> True, PlotRange -> {{-100, 100}, {-5, 20}},
  FrameLabel -> {"t-x", "Func"}],
 {x, 1, 100, 1}, Delimiter, {a, 0, 10}, {b, 0, 10}, {c, 0, 10}]
```

[image]

or,

```
Manipulate[Plot[a/(w + x)^2*(w)^2 + b/(w + x)*(w) + c, {w, -100,  100},
  AspectRatio -> 1, Frame -> True, PlotRange -> {{-100, 100}, {-5, 100}},
  FrameLabel -> {"t-x", "Func"}],
 {x, 1, 100, 1}, Delimiter, {a, 0, 10}, {b, 0, 10}, {c, 0, 10}]
```

[image]

Comment: thanks. This is exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: @Yasmin, my pleasure. Welcome to mma.se..